# How long do sorcerers live?

Tags: the-belgariad, the-malloreon

The Disciples of Aldur have lived for multiple thousand years. Do they not die of age?

Why is it that the Rivan Kings died when their time came, but not their ancestors? What does it mean for Belgarion as he is both a sorcerer and a Rivan King?

Comment: From memory, the Rivan Kings were not sorcerers, they were the protectors of the Orb of Aldur following Riva Iron Grips choice when escaping Cthol Mishrak.  As for sorcerers, it seems that the practice of sorcery extends life indefinitely (Senji in the University of Mallorea is an example), or until the sorcerer becomes "bored" and wills himself to unexist.
Don't have any references with me at the moment, hence this is a comment only

Comment: @Alith What about Belgarion? He definitely is a sorcerer, so one would assume he lives indefinitely, right?

Comment: It's possible yes, in fact I think there was a pasage in the Belgariad that hinted at this, and the fact that Ce'Nedra (with her Dryad heritage) would also be long lived.

Comment: There is one in the malorean, in reference to the future number of daughters he will have. Whic

Comment: @GarretGang That’s somewhat cut off, the comment.

Comment: I always assumed the long life of sorcerers was in service to the prophecies so Garion probably won't live forever, nor any of the others now.

Comment: Yeah, accidently sent off the content before noticing it. It is in  seereress of Kell 2nd to last Charley on the way home with both, spoiler, polgara and cenedra having morning sickness cuz they are pregnant.

Comment: *Chapter, and I dislike auto correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the kings of Riva (or united Aloria) before Belgarion were sorcerers. Riva Iron Grip and Beldaran were, neither one of them, sorcerers, despite Beldaran being descended from two (Belgarath and Poledra). The Prophecy didn't need them to be, so they weren't.

Eddings never really explores the timeline past the advent of Eriond and the birth of Polgara's twins. We have one hint, in the form of a citation from, *The Lives of Belgarion the Great*, which title suggests that Belgarion went on to do other things. We also know that his son is marked as a Keeper of the Orb, which would allow Belgarion and Ce'Nedra to eventually abdicate the throne in Prince Geran's stead. Whether Geran, Princess Beldaran, or any of the other daughters Belgarion and Ce'Nedra seem fated to have, turn out to be sorcerers was left unanswered.

Comment: +1 but "The Prophecy didn't need them to be, so they weren't" - we learn in the meeting with Senji that "even the gods themselves don't know how [the ability to do sorcery] arises", so although it *might* be that the Prophecies bestow sorcery ability, that's not in the text (iirc)